# A family of analytic functions satisfying a certain inequality is a normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that if a family of holomorphic functions $\{f\}$ on a domain $D$ satisfies $|f'(z)|\leq e^{|f(z)|}$ for every function $f$ in the family then it is a normal family. I think I have to use Marty's theorem to show this, but it doesn't seem to help directly. So I tried considering the family of functions $\{e^f\}$ but it does'nt seem to help.

Can someone please help me with this problem. Its from Gamelin 12.1.10.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify exactly what you mean by "normal family". Because there are various flavors of normal families out there - the most common/elementary one is "uniformly bounded on compact sets", and this is clearly false for that version (consider the family of constant functions).

Comment: I mean normal as a family of meromorphic functions in the extended complex plane.

Comment: Marty's Theorem?

Comment: It is a straightforward corollary of the previous exercise 12.1.9.

Comment: Ah, yes it does follow immediately from the previous exrecise which I have not even attemted. But thanks.