# Show all holomorphic function $f: \Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|f'(z)|\leq e^{|f(z)|}$ forms a normal family, where $\Omega$ is a plane region.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, normal-families

Here I mean normal family of meromorphic functions, which means every sequence ${f_k}$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$, and the limit is holomorphic or identically equals $\infty$

I tried to show all such functions $f$ are uniformly bounded on every compact subset of $\Omega$ and use Montel theorem. But I find it not so easy… So what else could I try? (Thanks to Theo, now I know that this approach will never work…)

Comment: Perhaps this is my exhaustion showing, but is this true as written? Take $\mathcal{F} = \{f_n:\overline{B(0;1)}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f_n(z)=n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. This family isn't normal, but it's contained within the family mentioned in the question (for $\Omega = \overline{B(0;1)}$).

Comment: @Theo Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that in this question “normal” means normal family of meromorphic functions…

Comment: @Theo Emm… this example tells that the usual Montel theorem may not work…

Comment: See the comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559393/42969.